# Core dumped when I run the program

Tags: c++, pointers, struct

When I try to run the code it asks for the first input, but next it show a core dumped.

And I have some doubts, how can I correct that fgets warnings?

And please if this code can be optimized please tell me, I`m trying to make
efficient code :D

Compile with these:

g++ -O2 -Wall Proy2.cpp -o Proy2

Code:

```
#include < cstdio >

#include < iostream >

using namespace std;

int main(){

    typedef struct PC{

    char Brand[20];
    char Model[20];
    char Serial[20];
    char Processor[10];

    };

    PC PC1[5],*machine;

    unsigned int i;

    for(i = 0; i < 4; i++){

    cout <<"Insert PC brand: ";
        fgets(machine->Brand, 20, stdin); fflush(stdin);

    cout <<"Insert PC model: ";
        fgets(machine->Model, 20, stdin); fflush(stdin);

    cout <<"Insert PC serial: ";
        fgets(machine->Serial, 20, stdin); fflush(stdin);

    cout <<"Insert PC processor: ";
        fgets(machine->Processor, 10, stdin); fflush(stdin);

    printf("PC Brand : %s", PC1[i].Brand);
    printf("PC Model : %s", PC1[i].Model);
    printf("PC Serial : %s", PC1[i].Serial);
    printf("PC Processor: %s", PC1[i].Processor);

    PC1[i] = *machine;

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: your `machine` variable is never initialized, if that fixes it, tell me to make it a full-fledged answer :)

Comment: "Core dumped trying to compile" - you seem to be saying the *compiler* crashed? That's unusual (but not unheard-of).

Comment: Please decide if you're going to use C or C++; `fgets` should be `getline`, and `fflush(stdin):` is illegal. And, of course, you need `machine = new PC;` to fix your immediate problem.

Comment: Ok, it works, but now it prints garbage, and thanks for the advice of initialized variable

Comment: Your character arrays should be replaced by `std::string`.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you define a structure inside a function?  It is not necessary in C or C++.

Comment: For efficiency, I prefer to make the prompts as `static const char` arrays and use the `cout.write` method.  This avoids any overhead of formatting by the `operator<<`.

Comment: Your dealing with I/O, and waiting for User input; optimization and efficiency is futile.

Comment: Thomas, can you give me an example of cout.write? When I try to use it my code dont compile.. And the static const char is for the struct? Thanks

Comment: **Rolled back** the edits because they changed the question substantially after answers had been posted.

Comment: **Changed the title** to remove the misleading info that core was dumped while compiling the program

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cout` is C++, `printf` is C. `fgets` is also C, and  should be `getline` (C++). You have to chose the language, not mix both. `Char*` is C and `string` is C++

Your class or struct shouldn't be in your main

```
#include <cstdio>

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

typedef struct PC{

    string Brand;
    string Model;
    string Serial;
    string Processor;

};

int main(){

    PC *PC1[5]; // pointer of pointers
    PC *machine=new PC[4];

    unsigned int i;

    for(i = 0; i < 4; i++){

        cout <<"Insert PC brand: ";
        cin >> machine->Brand;

        cout <<"Insert PC model: ";
        cin >> machine->Model;

        cout <<"Insert PC serial: ";
        cin >> machine->Serial;

        cout <<"Insert PC processor: ";
        cin >> machine->Processor;

        PC1[i] = machine; // you store the machine in PC1

        cout << "PC Brand : " << PC1[i]->Brand << endl;
        cout << "PC Model : " <<PC1[i]->Model << endl;
        cout << "PC Serial : " <<PC1[i]->Serial << endl;
        cout << "PC Processor: " <<PC1[i]->Processor << endl;

    }

    return 0;
}
```

You use `PC1[5]` and in the loop you are only giving 4 elements (0 to 3 is 4 elements). I thing you want to change your loop

Comment: Replace the arrays with `std::vector` and your answer will be more brilliant.

Comment: Bit89 doesn't seem to know C or C++ well, he's not ready yet for vector

Comment: I know vectors, but in my opinion simple array have better performance, please tell me if I`m wrong

Comment: `printf` and `fgets` and `char*` are all in C++. There's no rule that you must use stream I/O.  In fact stream I/O has a lot of problems.

Comment: @Bit89: Vectors and arrays have the same or very similar access times.  Any differences are considered as micro-optimization.

Answer (score 1):

You define two variables

PC PC1[5],*machine;

Means

PC1 is array of size 5 and each element is PC (each is already initialized  with default ctor )

machine is ptr to PC , and uninitialized and not allocated

Then you are storing at machine

fgets(machine->Brand, 20, stdin)

and get core dumps as machine is uninitialized

Probably you are guessing the solution now
which is to initialize machine

like below inside loop before assigning anything

machine = &PC1[i];

By the way, typedef is not required in C++ when you are defining struct/class as it is automatically typedef-ed

Answer (score 0):

Here you print uninitialized variable:

```
printf("PC Brand : %s", PC1[i].Brand);
```

and on the following lines.  You never wrote any data into `PC1[i]`.  Instead you wrote data into the object that you `new`'d and pointed `machine` at.

Later on you have the line:

```
PC1[i] = *machine;
```

I guess you meant for that line to be before the `printf` lines.

Note that there is no need to use dynamic allocation. You could write `PC machine;` instead.  In fact you could read directly into `PC1[i]` without even having `machine` at all.